# Get Single greatest date for each record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, greatest-n-per-group

I have a list of Devices with a gps data table. I would like to grab the last gps coordinates received for each device in the query.

```
SELECT g.[TimeStamp], d.DeviceId, p.IsHistorical, g.Latitude, g.Longitude, g.Speed, g.Bearing, g.Fix, g.SatelliteCount, p.MessageTypeId
FROM Obd.Device d
LEFT JOIN obd.Packet p ON p.DeviceId = d.Id
LEFT JOIN obd.GPSData g ON g.PacketId = p.Id
WHERE d.ISDId = 1000 AND (g.Latitude IS NOT NULL OR g.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part selects MAX(TimeStamp) for every device that match the conditions, the use a INNER JOIN to select records WHERE DeviceID and MAX(TimeStamp) are the same.

```
WITH MDEV AS
(
    SELECT MAX(g.[TimeStamp]) MTS, d.DeviceId DevID
    FROM Obd.Device d
         LEFT JOIN obd.Packet p ON p.DeviceId = d.Id
         LEFT JOIN obd.GPSData g ON g.PacketId = p.Id
    WHERE d.ISDId = 1000 AND (g.Latitude IS NOT NULL OR g.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY d.DeviceId
)
    SELECT g.[TimeStamp], d.DeviceId, p.IsHistorical, g.Latitude, 
           g.Longitude, g.Speed, g.Bearing, g.Fix, g.SatelliteCount, p.MessageTypeId
    FROM Obd.Device d
         LEFT JOIN obd.Packet p ON p.DeviceId = d.Id
         LEFT JOIN obd.GPSData g ON g.PacketId = p.Id
         INNER JOIN MDEV
                ON MDEV.DevID = d.DeviceId
                AND MDEV.MTS = g.[TimeStamp] 
    WHERE d.ISDId = 1000 
          AND (g.Latitude IS NOT NULL OR g.Longitude IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Is MDEV supposed to be a temple table or something ?

Comment: It's a CTE (Common table expression). Which database are you working on?

Comment: it's similar to this: http://rextester.com/SDBMU66720

Comment: Have found myself using CTE extensively now - Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use window functions, either `ROW_NUMBER()` or `MIN()`:

```
WITH
  ct AS
  ( SELECT 
        g.[TimeStamp], d.DeviceId, p.IsHistorical, 
        g.Latitude, g.Longitude, g.Speed, g.Bearing, 
        g.Fix, g.SatelliteCount, p.MessageTypeId,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceID
                                ORDER BY g.[TimeStamp] DESC)
    FROM Obd.Device d
      JOIN obd.Packet p ON p.DeviceId = d.Id
      JOIN obd.GPSData g ON g.PacketId = p.Id
    WHERE d.ISDId = 1000 AND (g.Latitude IS NOT NULL OR g.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
  ) 
SELECT 
    [TimeStamp], DeviceId, IsHistorical, 
    Latitude, Longitude, Speed, Bearing, 
    Fix, SatelliteCount, MessageTypeId
FROM ct
WHERE rn = 1 ;
```

Irrelevant to the question but the condition on `g.Latitude` and `g.Longitude` makes the `LEFT` joins equivalent to `INNER` joins.